# Ansible lineinfile not copying last line to server

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I am trying to copy a secret Python settings file from a settings server to the production environment. Since the settings contains passwords I am using Ansible Vault.

My playbook looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: production
  tasks:
  - include_vars: settings.yml
  - name: Set properties
    lineinfile:
      dest: ~/temp/deploy
      regexp: "{{ item.split('=')[0] }}\\s*="
      line: "{{ item }}"
    with_lines: echo "{{ config }}"
```

And my settings.yml looks like this:

```
config:  |
  ASD='DEF'
  PROGRAM='PROG'
  PASSWORD='MAGNUS123'
  TEMP='TEST'
```

However when I run the playbook I get the file:

```
ASD='DEF'
PROGRAM='PROG'
PASSWORD='MAGNUS123'
```

Even though Ansible claims the last line is also copied:

```
changed: [ssh.pythonanywhere.com] => (item=ASD='DEF' )
changed: [ssh.pythonanywhere.com] => (item=PROGRAM='PROG')
changed: [ssh.pythonanywhere.com] => (item=PASSWORD='MAGNUS123')
changed: [ssh.pythonanywhere.com] => (item=TEMP='TEST')
changed: [ssh.pythonanywhere.com] => (item=)
```

What am I doing wrong to cause this?

Ansible version:

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.4.1.0
  config file = None
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.2 (default, Jul 17 2017, 16:44:45) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)]
```

Comment: I'm curious: did you invent this yourself or found somewhere?

Comment: Invented it myself, if someone has a solution along the lines of "Scrap this and use this" I'll be all ears

Comment: That would require a definition of the problem to solve.

Comment: I have a python settings file on a server encrypted with Ansible Vault. I want to update the settings file on the production environment so that if the setting is present, it is updated, if it's not present it is appended to the file.

Comment: Why not use a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing something completely unnecessary (skip to the bottom), but let's give it a try...

> What am I doing wrong to cause this?

If you run the following:

```
- shell: echo "{{ config }}" | hexdump
  register: echo

- debug:
    var: echo.stdout
```

You'll see that the output ends with:

```
54 45 4d 50 3d 27 54 45 53 54 27 0a 0a
```

which is `TEMP='TEST'` followed by two newline characters. When used in `with_lines` loop this will cause two iterations -- the last one with an empty value passed to `item`.

Now, think what happens to your arguments when `item` is empty:

`regexp` becomes `\\s*=` and `line` is empty.

In other words you instruct Ansible to replace some line containing `=` with an empty line.

If the starting point is an empty file, Ansible does the following:

1. Adds `ASD='DEF'` line.
2. Adds `PROGRAM='PROG'` line.
3. Adds `PASSWORD='MAGNUS123'` line.
4. Adds `TEMP='TEST'` line.
5. Replaces a line with `=` with an empty line (in fact it happens to be the very last line).

And that is the result you get: three lines and an empty one.

---

<sup>You can also arrive at the same conclusion simply running using `debug` module to display the values of `"{{ item.split('=')[0] }}\\s*="` and `{{ item }}` which you pass to the `lineinfile` arguments.</sup>

---

`echo` has `-n` argument ("*Do not print the trailing newline character*"), but for a reason beyond my current understanding, it does not change the result (check with `hexdump`).

If you however replaced `echo` with `printf` -- the dangling `0x0a` is not there and you get expected result  (check with `hexdump`).

---

All this, apart from being a nice conundrum, is yet another argument **against using `linefile` module** in Ansible.

Use [`copy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/copy_module.html) (you can protect the whole file with Ansible Vault - see `decrypt` argument) or [`template`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/template_module.html) (you can have a public template and store the variable values in a Vault-protected form). Define the desired state, do not rely on current state. Period.

Comment: That you for both telling me what was wrong (that worked perfectly) and what I should use instead